# Error in importing tensorflow

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, tensorflow

I followed instructions in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv_install Virtualenv but when I type this in python in Ubuntu terminal `import tensorflow as tf`
 I got this message:
`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow`
What did I wrong?

Comment: did you activate your virualenv. ?

Answer (score 0):

did you install the tenserflow module in your virtualenv?

after activating the virtualenv 
try to run the relevant pip command to install

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only:
(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled:
(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Mac OS X, CPU only:
(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```